# Python27 IDLE GUI stopped working

Tags: python, user-interface

For some reason my Python IDLE interface stopped working :( I ran a some code which seems to have been buggy since i couldn't even exit it with ctrl+F6. I had to close the IDLE window down and since then it won't launch anymore. Reinstalling Python didn't make any difference....any ideas to help me get it runnig again would be great. Strangely the Python Command Line opens up fine...

OS: Vista

thanks,

Baba

Comment: this question does not belong in SO

Answer (score 0):

uninstalling Python AND manually deleting the Python installation folder (which isn't removed by default when uninstalling) allowed me to re-install Python successfully